# Sacar un archivo de un commit local

Tags: git

He hecho un commit, y por error subí un archivo que no quería, y al tratar de hacer pull me marca un error con ese archivo, ¿Como puedo deshacer los cambios solo en ese archivo si el commit esta en local?

En cosola me marca esto:

```
Rutas no fusionadas:
  (usa "git reset HEAD <archivo>..." para sacar del área de stage)
  (usa "git add <archivo>..." para marcar una resolución)

    ambos modificados:     Documents/Project/Controller/archivoController.java
```

Answer (score 0):

primero ejecuta este comando, este funciona para revertir el commit:

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard
```

después agrega solo los archivos que quieres subir:

```
git add [ruta del archivo]
```

y por ultimo

```
git commit -m "mensaje"
```

Comment: lo revirtió pero me desapareció todos mis cambios, por suerte lo comprimi, debo de poner un indice en el ```HEAD```?

Answer (score 0):

Lo soluciones primero haciendo:

```
git log --oneline
```

Esto para listar los commit y sus ids

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues `git reset --soft 890c14a91`, esto para revertir los cambios hasta ese id de commit, se deshace el commit sin perder los cambios.

Comment: Aunque hayan pasado años: ¡no olvides aceptar la respuesta que te ha sido más útil! Tu pregunta está siendo relanzada una y otra vez al inicio. Según la [línea de tiempo](/posts/346664/timeline) de la pregunta, ya es la tercera vez.